# Rellenar polígono en canvas con imagen ¿pintar una zona de la imagen en especifico?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Buen día espero me puedan ayudar, descargue un ejemplo de como agregar una imagen en un canvas y que pudieras cambiar el color de cada elemento como si fuese el PAINT de Windows, funciona con imágenes coloreadas, el problema que tengo son con imágenes para niños para que puedan meter el relleno de color, me rellena absolutamente todo menos las lineas del trazo, no se que condicionante puedo meter para que realmente en un área en especifico lo pinte no todos los que sean similares al color que intento modificar.

Les paso el código del HTML y les anexo la imagen que intento colorear.

[image: Les adjunto la imagen que intento colorear por secciones]

```js
var colorNuevoHex;
var mouseX, mouseY;
var marco;
var contexto;
var imagenCompleta;
var colorZonaHex;
var colorZonaRGB;

function cargarDibujo() {
  marco = document.getElementById('dibujo');
  contexto = marco.getContext('2d');

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls1LW.png';

  img.onload = function() {
    contexto.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    imagenCompleta = contexto.getImageData(0, 0, marco.width, marco.height);
    contexto.putImageData(imagenCompleta, 0, 0);
  }
}

function setColor(color) {
  colorNuevoHex = color;
  document.getElementById('colorElegido').style.backgroundColor = colorNuevoHex;
}

function cambiarColor() {
  var imgData = contexto.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);
  var colorNuevoRGB = hexToRgb(colorNuevoHex);

  colorZonaRGB = [imgData.data[0], imgData.data[1], imgData.data[2]];
  colorZonaHex = rgbToHex(imgData.data[0], imgData.data[1], imgData.data[2]);

  for (var i = 0; i < imagenCompleta.data.length; i += 4) {
    if ((imagenCompleta.data[i] == imgData.data[0]) && (imagenCompleta.data[i + 1] == imgData.data[1]) && (imagenCompleta.data[i + 2] == imgData.data[2])) {
      imagenCompleta.data[i] = colorNuevoRGB.r;
      imagenCompleta.data[i + 1] = colorNuevoRGB.g;
      imagenCompleta.data[i + 2] = colorNuevoRGB.b;
    }
  }

  contexto.putImageData(imagenCompleta, 0, 0);
}

function setCoords(e) {
  if (e.offsetX) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
  } else if (e.layerX) {
    mouseX = e.layerX;
    mouseY = e.layerY;
  }

  document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML = mouseX + ' X' + ', ' + mouseY + ' Y';
}

function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
  // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
  var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
  hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
    return r + r + g + g + b + b;
  });

  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
}
```

```html
<body onload="cargarDibujo();">
  <canvas id="dibujo" width="500" height="500" onclick="cambiarColor();" onmousemove="setCoords(event);" style="position: relative; border: 0;"></canvas>
  <hr />
  <div id="colorElegido" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
  <p id="coords"></p>
  <hr />
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #FFFFFF;" onclick="setColor('#FFFFFF');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #FF0000;" onclick="setColor('#FF0000');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #00FF00;" onclick="setColor('#00FF00');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #0000FF;" onclick="setColor('#0000FF');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #000000;" onclick="setColor('#000000');"></button>
</body>
```

Comment: No creo que se pueda hacer directamente usando métodos de CANVAS, pero se podría hacer "a mano" con una función en JS, pero no debe ser tarea fácil.

Comment: Otro tema, es que usando una imagen externa, tendrás problemas de CORS si intentas manipularla.

Comment: phostoshop creo que lo hace con seleccion el usuario seleciona que parte asi saben que pixeles pintar y creo que tambien verificar si hay lineas trazadas para evitar pintarlas. Es algo costoso pero no imposible

Comment: He actualizado el código, ahora funciona bastante mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El objeto `canvas` no dispone de un método para rellenar zonas, de manera que hay que hacerlo a mano.
Un sistema podría ser el pintado de píxeles adyacentes recursivamente, pero nos encontraremos con el problema de la pila, ya que pintar zonas grandes requeriría mucha memoria.
**EDIT:** He retocado el código de relleno, para que funcione a base de lineas y no de píxeles, de manera que hace menos llamadas recursivas. Parece que funciona mejor y es más estable.
Al usar una imagen externa, al intentar modificarla dará un error de CORS, por lo que en este ejemplo, he codificado la imagen en base64.

Como funciona:
Almacena el color nuevo y el de fondo
Si el color nuevo y el de fondo son distintos, llama a la funcion rellenar.
funcion rellenar:

- pinta la linea horizontal del punto seleccionado.
- Para cada pixel pintado, vuelve a llamar la funcion rellenar, para el pixel superior e inferior, en caso que sean del color del fondo a rellenar.

```js
var colorNuevoHex;
var mouseX, mouseY;
var marco;
var contexto;
var imagenCompleta;
var colorZonaHex;
var colorZonaRGB;

function cargarDibujo() {
  marco = document.getElementById('dibujo');
  contexto = marco.getContext('2d');

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAc0AAAInAQMAAADAvJAnAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAACEZVhJZk1NACoAAAAIAAUBEgADAAAAAQABAAABGgAFAAAAAQAAAEoBGwAFAAAAAQAAAFIBKAADAAAAAQACAACHaQAEAAAAAQAAAFoAAAAAAAAASAAAAAEAAABIAAAAAQADoAEAAwAAAAEAAQAAoAIABAAAAAEAAAHNoAMABAAAAAEAAAInAAAAAJTR+/4AAAFZaVRYdFhNTDpjb20uYWRvYmUueG1wAAAAAAA8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJYTVAgQ29yZSA2LjAuMCI+CiAgIDxyZGY6UkRGIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+CiAgICAgIDxyZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24gcmRmOmFib3V0PSIiCiAgICAgICAgICAgIHhtbG5zOnRpZmY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20vdGlmZi8xLjAvIj4KICAgICAgICAgPHRpZmY6T3JpZW50YXRpb24+MTwvdGlmZjpPcmllbnRhdGlvbj4KICAgICAgPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+CiAgIDwvcmRmOlJERj4KPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+Chle4QcAAA8rSURBVHja7d3Lbt02GgBgniqIvDBMz84Lw0qQF/DsvDCsBAGmr5GgL+DuvAgsOceIZjFo3mDyKlI0GC/7CCPViy5LoxsGw4rDi+6ipJ80Ek8BuwO3tvUd3cifPy/SoJA7fhEUuVNXyekjfaSP9JE+0v83WrlTFrrTwJlS7E49d7pxptB200Rfhs70TeBKC+AlNlHmOdNq40ozHkfONA0dac6LwJFuOfWdKewSG2jCYZfYQMXRgi6xmYIusYGKYgi6xFNaCQq6xGZKPCcqo1qxcaYpJDc3UwS5xFNKQ1EkIJfYSKkPCRRGWmDmu1AS8TiAlGIDDai4vsiJIiR+l0YOtEBIlKUidKOBPGw3ykEt5ZRm6jvxnWnhOdBcfY83DnQrv1Wb1JVSv4gcaeqT0J6qS4s2NHCjDG0YdqOiWFS+PZV7Qwfn6+3OhKowjOgF2TjR1KPnKXKhDAX0GVqtsVMaiCgstLdaYyeUBQT5gvqrNXZKDxD6UVzjYLXGTilCvjhNFK3GUxPlccg2vLKmFIWCyiDhWVNxT54GabCei0zppc/3jkQQX+0BTemFx/f2ZSRea2ONFCFxY+Lz0JKS81c8RrKNXavsU0pKnm5kdGIOlCGVOlXYmr5C8gKJXM+3pVS1dKI4rZWJCRVhSe5UFqcreyrPMT3EdetjQ3UgvvB5YUvVdaUbccQksqOl/gBfZJgrKdsMRWGZVyiwo1n92zKnTlTExCIvdrE9FUEmIh468+2ozAdiJELME8TtqQjEKKTi/nq2VB7unohtwUpJnNJKBGJ+FFSiJKd29L0o/p/4big7HYUdjRE69UWRSGV1jywpFg16fKZqXmhHsRwOSS9kAKd2NBG/e8tLebx8OSZOaczpHa/U1MdyAjSlKBJ71UlIZUc/CrrhsSqDy+3khO7thHTD6qkaz44ehsxrepJbW1o9RfVJXtnRnbDrg6ZWFIsEBDXnWNjSuJ3PWizEUxqTdqfLhXhKK9RlAtSOpqgrCIuFeEIPUO83zIqifuBeLMRT2i98i4V4Sgf3w4aODtFzp1t3mrnT1J0W96CRMyX3oKEzpTZ0WOCXyv/Xo0tV5+vRparzFen2QWj2ILR4ELpQ674iXah1K/X1PnSh1n1FulDr5mkcuFLRo1RXyLemIqPQLa09lQPMqqm1p7EnB7v4UoWdZjD6E+SJqtFaa6omUpn826DC/gGguu8sJ5MG9AuApmElMi85XTGosBRAkUhsRZcQ29PKk/fVr8adMxqtUorVfeWbUV0n65QEqSdvUDqm4RJVpaeI5H1NcREO6zqApkx16TyR1A5psEqv9GybHJoe0GKd+nqb9NIfhom0n7caaYX1CG8RegOabnoZurETKjbXfSMq/t2ProWH8AqloT4u5meDCEO8OFih5LI+Lq8YUBr0746Zvqs//IoMBucY7ueMRlo0dyQV/9Gjld+vghMqo0LWlL7i3YByP1+jeVNd5JH3I8z16zW6bY6LnmE52tB+7bxYo36zJxZgNYDafKHNEpVng5P6hwr7ovB1N2SVSlB/iQ/JuiOuNqv0qD09cUnLbuK58q6WqLhC7Kgtbtu8v3xi5b5KetrSvBRxrZ3bZ0GxQulpe2GykpNuapOFdI1etCW1JCKutWGFiX8WaDmghaTtANCXwQImEyWk/YlIOtMBng7yDimNRMT34LS7juLYRb27AtOyHNHUhbLTkIUz/cnp4L2gtwMazHQKTfQ2H1EKpBHPO1qdhSIQmxPFNXokqTnbM9KbHlWzJD6IihKQJ870ZkBlO7+F0bBPuaa5Cw0CebQZlCYfux+xogWIsgkVx0DuQSMQDQyUOlJxZ4yFeEKrCRV3ht2DBiCKDbT6BnRUmmS4wRDK8bgMw6lvogmQDuurHR1ECX4HpskoNqmyn4PodkBP7egwDltQbxT9FS0hVHQYBm1OpLpUIEo3o5bOig7bV1XPCYSSt4NW3YYWxSiXgNOsGGUwilIIzckgbyprGgHoVuRJg2yNMyj1Je1yxMyCYpFiDTJTFQ5NIXE6pEHDfj68taCBCNeDLNyOtt0GlcpLVgEok8lO0vY45KFLZoqmRtrr5wRwSiOxVdb2rk7tKBa5d9Onu2gYlHY9SfkZimIAlVsN+q9gSmQgpmddr9mSskCn7LpLpGgCookoCfUIAVY3WO4VRrdib824hG9B71S49prRENzQGxDN2jEYpOckpc/XaaloeqlHfvQwBJzK/lWoxhHrYQg4LeSwhx7linlDb0GUyMGXdmytpiWMRqJTrkb06gVzVlR0lOU4ItHFT6ZRMCoDZxrI0ct60Y+kdzAaNqtx67lYSQmIqggof908vGJBZRFSi97qqqeGoEBUVbIUhUUzgqLGzOCUqvvaoxGE6ogQo3b0zpbSbmoeSE0JoRpadKOymhvaKxPdulFTQmhBMwOtYLQ00QBEx11OeQIASvm0vEJpNO1yqssGo9REMYyGzpS5URUiAgP9CKKViSYwip2oKnCOVB6sb6A3MDrag1qYni/S3xq6HdNwjf4svxka0xThNfqxoaMKm8nB5dtFiptvowqbyedmFqm+nWq2YUxFLlQuUdZSMqYiHVmgP9errxSNRpTiJZrVc1ryStIxrXxD29zSNCo6Go6o6EqTeVrgtKVsQq+WKNlcKSrPaVTrZPq2SJE3R0WGW0R0nlLkt3RY6+RMIQmX6DFWVB3YoNbJdY00mDawLWVnQUcHtU4+IMSWqDi/jvZrHUOvVAdzgeI6EZCb9GsY8WRF8tk8FdBrab/WxVj+tJ02sB31dQqrPr3sH28kabZEE/1ImtqE9I9XHUO5vFf1gIumUe941ZkXC1RUDvWUis7Vot7xKkouFyjmKunWtN1OLkFQlelsnrKAqVk4Rbuja4IhOwtmKQ2ZTu0w77V18llATY/mKYl6tG2wUnmvVS6xN08L9E4fZRtS5UeohRqqbPnzNEUn+rKqol9XHf0QuW7p5mk8oHX51ym8otsFuncwoVSn8KpsZ3iW8qqmah+6/OupV/3IWLlA+Q7vqJroYjqF132eAkpVF7J+VkwHWbJEdY9TVzhZEqp6wYA+YQqkegWN7pfVD1Ys0noiT9ZVuhMKrgcnil1FGZCSk6Cdno71IF0Fpe9ws0y7QnVbECzQOiDJal5UuNkp9YzzBbM0q540SzlSDKB3Hc05arqRKJpbzjWlMkIkbd9VdH8B9EtH/XZCvPAtqDw13M7WosA8wcG5YQRe06L3Zxsq/lcvAkl9Gyq2rJqJXh2bZtafGam4Ujr/KtRfLamKxHW1g9NEUax2GlrTSK1+b2qAaTLHTHNVFn3eFkZbuu0WM9nSq6J9UGFmmZ6Blqr/m3ajIba06NZewWmhY0y35MU4SW2kRAdFz5l2aZdcqQekNBrSuffDGKkKNe3SjLmn3k00VLTtJ/UXnK1QVtO6QLC598DN03bsf98sTbQKyj69Mk7lL9I62WPYhuI+LSILyjWtkz3PONEGofIdFxY0UVS3F3K5kxtVz8zPLA030Vy3tDIQksiZNhxKM0239brSuSftTbRsqYoUhi3WaKaTu9nXOZkoqWml/pbOrQw3Uj3yUajGtUJza7RNlP6gqaqoBNkccE114h/vzT0tb6LsRUcZunSgqnskOuo2N6d+P0QlS6CIaXMP2ptoE7NlSiFcPPOMgonyjsqOmQutArWCXncb9NeXNbptaCz/2i9OUMqRKkllf6XyGs1bKuNT/yUtq7T5ir9TRbHXqtMISLefJaW95bs0BFKuaa8kwukvaqTiWW/zoLvIENpr6mjvPQEAWu1HPdplFhC601Hid7cKQLnoG7Y06coWhD7punPkPbKiH3o07Z42hdD3XTglRXf0y1S/YiXv0xMoVUeXdVWnvOsaLwgtuzT8qjdiDaFFW3WqTW/EDkJJm9VSvzdOCKH0Ve/nLZDqMW76tvk5jnp5NYS2tU62mtADvtP0uP5RjueUVrRqK6wIrsSOHkTd1tAiUa9D7ypszKgNzXoVllJo8VcpTMqvu83PEZxGPA2vgx4F1lcRxSJRhN53m7+JsQ3Fnzv6loKp6HsTvxtDFI1IAqQfxb0gXjeGyJaeChpRkZuSq6INE8wHUywofUkSFyqfvHpz3lEMpr6g7PikbWFZAKepoCculPkiaWKnh+11rUI4/RDy6mj3uQP9/qmgwZPuqZUIvtc9sRv83oU+PTqMOE6Nvd8V+t3RwWWEM+RA0dnBZZAUjvQMJ2QnsqYViiSlyIE+i3bO/Jwhp73unHk5exI6UC5oWSE3GmxK7kb/Lul7F1qhYJ/w94E15X+hKEDn/LMLJQjvnP/8iwPFhaAn/u/YgaYv8e6J50Tjl/gfh5v/utAnL/2fDhF3obuC7j6LEnv60+4bP9nbDx3o9eGb18lTN3r67HXy4SBwoLGk+Q7OHei747dJvus70pvSiabs+PlNee250Or4OCcfNrcu9ETR0oUeHOf0NXKgWXVw8lrQt/a0lJR5Oz+60MPjH9jz+K8OlB8ev6g218eO9HLz7317WvC9/ecB+ozsKRF0g1G+40j9+NZprz9JWsaRNeU82d946dvUiRb3oPFVel640uLYieZFHBfHxI2+jMnJRehIz13pm/ji5J0LLQU9OXSkz56cHp7B6K8jegynN2MqkuIwcKDkl4O/HR0BaTKm3+Oj4BOI+iN66Av6n3X66/htZ/T28Pvkn5C8qeCjF+rSH3CefIJQEtIp3YIymP5AYUtzEKWoGF5h9iIBUoY2U1oalgDD6G0Jek6yOvCGm1Uvbm4JjGJ/RL0cSDn+zUBhOWLCJ7Sk0Q2EbsfP/3uloKDkJ29WHPUoC0E0G7943oaOXmO9JWUVgFKu7bjqbMkdkPrj2XtJMSTlEhUdDX+V0zsOoky+CzIc0h+BNBjTjJ7z5A5AKToazQaWUErQeM1iyY7FpQLQAu0ZaA6hKdobNS93UMr5hzGtDsT5gui1Ox2/YfmLoAT0EOuU8p3o69NxdvWHoL2nf20o43FE34EoMVD5KLcDrfh1/5njJTq9Iv+K2KEjTaMKRtlkmzR0piK67oFo5U65iT4NnOkHR0ruRT+709yR0oBn7rTE35zKd+48CKWOtLoHxfehpv+vCwiVK0/dafUA9JM75cbFsd+Abv9sNH8Qevtno3cPQr/82egfD0L5I32kj/SRflMaudPQUXLyP/P0tArpi+xwAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

  img.onload = function() {
    contexto.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
}

function setColor(color) {
  colorNuevoHex = color;
  document.getElementById('colorElegido').style.backgroundColor = colorNuevoHex;
}


function rellenarFiguraCanvas(obj,x,y,color){
    
}

function cambiarColor() {
    var obj = marco;
    var w = obj.width;
    var h = obj.height;
    var context = obj.getContext('2d');
    var image = context.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var data = image.data;
    
    var x = mouseX;
    var y = mouseY;
    
    var offset=(y*w+x)*4;
    var fondoRGB = {r:data[offset],
                    g:data[offset+1],
                    b:data[offset+2]
    };

    if (!colorNuevoHex) colorNuevoHex="#FFFFFF";
    var colorNuevoRGB = hexToRgb(colorNuevoHex);
    
    var rellenar = function(x,y){
        var offset=(y*w+x)*4;
        var ini, fin;
        var salir=false;
        var yw=y*w;
        ini=x;
        for (let i=x; !salir && i>=0 ; i--){
            offset=(yw+i)*4;
            salir= !(data[offset]==fondoRGB.r && data[offset+1]==fondoRGB.g && data[offset+2]==fondoRGB.b);
            if (!salir){
                data[offset]=colorNuevoRGB.r;
                data[offset+1]=colorNuevoRGB.g;
                data[offset+2]=colorNuevoRGB.b;
                ini=i;
            }
        }
        salir=false;
        fin=x;
        for (let i=x+1; !salir && i<=w ; i++){
            offset=(yw+i)*4;
            salir= !(data[offset]==fondoRGB.r && data[offset+1]==fondoRGB.g && data[offset+2]==fondoRGB.b);
            if (!salir){
                data[offset]=colorNuevoRGB.r;
                data[offset+1]=colorNuevoRGB.g;
                data[offset+2]=colorNuevoRGB.b;
                fin=i;
            }
        }
        
        var wy_ant=(y-1)*w;
        var wy_post=(y+1)*w;
        
        for (let i=ini; i<=fin ; i++){
            if (y>0){
                offset=(wy_ant+i)*4;
                if (data[offset]==fondoRGB.r && data[offset+1]==fondoRGB.g && data[offset+2]==fondoRGB.b){
                    rellenar (i,y-1);
                }
            }
            if (y<h){
                offset=(wy_post+i)*4;
                if (data[offset]==fondoRGB.r && data[offset+1]==fondoRGB.g && data[offset+2]==fondoRGB.b){
                    rellenar (i,y+1);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    if (!(fondoRGB.r==colorNuevoRGB.r && fondoRGB.g==colorNuevoRGB.g && fondoRGB.b==colorNuevoRGB.b)){
        rellenar(x,y);
        context.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
    }
 }

function setCoords(e) {
  if (e.offsetX) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
  } else if (e.layerX) {
    mouseX = e.layerX;
    mouseY = e.layerY;
  }

  document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML = mouseX + ' X' + ', ' + mouseY + ' Y';
}

function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
  // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
  var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
  hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
    return r + r + g + g + b + b;
  });

  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
}
```

```html
<body onload="cargarDibujo();">
  <canvas id="dibujo" width="500" height="500" onclick="cambiarColor();" onmousemove="setCoords(event);" style="position: relative; border: 0;"></canvas>
  <hr />
  <div id="colorElegido" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
  <p id="coords"></p>
  <hr />
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #FFFFFF;" onclick="setColor('#FFFFFF');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #FF0000;" onclick="setColor('#FF0000');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #00FF00;" onclick="setColor('#00FF00');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #0000FF;" onclick="setColor('#0000FF');"></button>
  <button style="display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #000000;" onclick="setColor('#000000');"></button>
</body>
```